# App does not rendered german text correctly

Tags: android, character-encoding

My app takes some csv files as input and displays the content of these files. Some lines contains german letters (ä, ß, ü, ...), my app does not render these letters correctly.

I changed the encoding specified in the Manifest to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-3"?>` (even if I think that the encoding declaration is specific to the Manifest itself and not the app), I selected German as the language in the Settings of the AVD, I also included the following option in gradle.build:

```
compileOptions{
    encoding "ISO-8859-3"
}
```

None of my attempts worked and my app is still writing the text uncorrectly.

How to do to have the csv file correctly rendered in the Gui of my app?

Note: the files are correctly written in AndroidStudio

**UPDATE**

I found where the problem came from and the solution. So it seems that the problem comes from the csv file. I opened my csv file with a text Editor and saved it with explicit UTF-8, now its content is correctly written in the gui of my app.

**note**

A turnaround is to specify an encoding when reading the file with `InputStreamReader(my_csv, "ISO-8859-3")` but I guess it could introduce problem in case that in future csv files are well formated

Comment: Does the font you are using support German?

Comment: How does your method with the `InputStream` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the problem came from and the solution. So the problem comes from the csv file formating. Indeed I opened my csv file with a text editor and saved it with explicit UTF-8, now its content is correctly written in the gui of my app.

**note**

A turnaround is to specify an encoding when reading the file with `InputStreamReader(my_csv, "ISO-8859-3")` but I guess it could introduce problem in case that in future csv files are well formated

I searched on the false direction, the problem was how I read the files. I had to specify the encoding when I read the csv files:

```
stream = new InputStreamReader(the_file, "ISO-8859-3");
```

Update: It seems actually that the problem comes from the csv file. I opened my csv file with a text Editor and saved it with explicit UTF-8, now I don't need to specify the encoding type with InputStreamReader, and its content is correctly written

Answer (score 0):

i think your encoding is false. Here is a link with all encondings : 
[List encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

A you can see, the encoding for the german is **ISO 8859-16** 
(ISO 8859-3 is for languages like Turkish)

I hope this encoding will display your text correctly :)

Don't forget to precise the encoding when reading the csv :

```
new InputStreamReader(your-csv_file, "ISO-8859-16");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think the problem came from the csv file

Comment: @OLeeCsobert  "the problems came from the csv file" .... do you solved your problem ? If it's done, could you update your first post to indcate what was wrong in your csv file ? It could be usefull for others people .... and because i'm curious too :)

Edit : i 'm just seeing your response about the editor.   Good luck for your app development ;)

Comment: I updated my question and answer.. I just have to wait to mark my own answer as the solution. Thanks again for your answer